Firebase/firebase genkit, app hosting nextJS project with genkit
I am trying to app host a nextJS application that uses genkit and firebase-admin. It is a RAG chatbot and locally it works however I cant seem to be able to hosting it with firebase due to peer dependency conflicts.
Tried updating firebase and genkit and firebase tools to the latest.
This is the error message i have received.
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: @genkit-ai/firebase@0.9.7
npm error Found: genkit@0.9.6
npm error node_modules/genkit
npm error   genkit@"^0.9.4" from the root project
npm error   peer genkit@"0.9.6" from @genkit-ai/googleai@0.9.6
npm error   node_modules/@genkit-ai/googleai
npm error     @genkit-ai/googleai@"^0.9.4" from the root project
npm error   1 more (@genkit-ai/vertexai)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer genkit@"0.9.7" from @genkit-ai/firebase@0.9.7
npm error node_modules/@genkit-ai/firebase
npm error   @genkit-ai/firebase@"^0.9.7" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: genkit@0.9.7
npm error node_modules/genkit
npm error   peer genkit@"0.9.7" from @genkit-ai/firebase@0.9.7
npm error   node_modules/@genkit-ai/firebase
npm error     @genkit-ai/firebase@"^0.9.7" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-12-05T20_21_42_782Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2024-12-05T20_21_42_782Z-debug-0.log. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-east1/a980b836-aa34-44bf-b7d3-4487e45b59bb?project=*******.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        **********(us-east1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions

The code sample below where I use firebase admin:
import { devLocalIndexerRef } from "@genkit-ai/dev-local-vectorstore";
import { textEmbedding004, vertexAI } from "@genkit-ai/vertexai";
import { genkit } from "genkit";
import {} from "@genkit-ai/core";
import {
  initializeApp,
  AppOptions,
  cert,
  ServiceAccount,
} from "firebase-admin/app"; // firebase admin
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";// firebase admin
import { defineFirestoreRetriever } from "@genkit-ai/firebase";



const ai = genkit({
  plugins: [

    vertexAI({
      googleAuth: {
        
        projectId: "********",
        scopes: ["********"],
        credentials: {
          client_id:
          "********",
          project_id: "********",
          client_email: "********",
          client_secret: "",
          private_key:
          "********"
        },
      },
      projectId: "********",
      location: "********",
    }),
  ],
});


const credentials: ServiceAccount = {
  projectId: "********",
  privateKey:
  "********",
  clientEmail:
  "********",
};
const options: AppOptions = {
  credential: cert(credentials),
};
const app = initializeApp(options);


export const faqRetriever = defineFirestoreRetriever(ai, {
  name: "faqRetriever",
  firestore: getFirestore(app),
  collection: "studentFaq",
  contentField: "text",
  vectorField: "embedding",
  embedder: textEmbedding004, // Import from '@genkit-ai/googleai' or '@genkit-ai/vertexai'
  distanceMeasure: "COSINE", // "EUCLIDEAN", "DOT_PRODUCT", or "COSINE" (default)
});

export const articleIndexer = devLocalIndexerRef("studentQA");

export const chunkingConfig = {
  minLength: 1000,
  maxLength: 2000,
  splitter: "sentence",
  overlap: 100,
  delimiters: "",
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
} as any;

// type declaration above, consider updating types

I use nvm version: 0.39.1
node version: v20.18.1
macOS: 14.4.1 (23E224)
Using latest firebase CLI.
commands: firebase init
. select hosting option
. select use experimental framework
. select nextjs
. select using typescript.
then command: firebase deploy .
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Adding a .npmrc file to the root directory,
and in that file adding the line: legacy-peer-deps=true. seems to patch the issue and deployment works after that.
